# How to join paths nice way?

Tags: python, path

What I have:

```py
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
filepath = 'files/one.txt'
request_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, filepath)
print(request_path, filepath, BASE_DIR)
```

And it prints

```
/files/one.txt /files/one.txt /home/pavel/Dev/AiPOSiZI/Lab_1
```

what means paths weren't joined.

But

```py
os.path.join('/home/pavel/Dev/AiPOSiZI/Lab_1/', 'files/one.txt')
```

(I've added / to the end of /home/... and removed / from the beginning of /files/...)
works well.

I could just manually add and remove / from paths but I wonder if there is any more elegant way to join them

Comment: From the `os.path.join` documentation: "_If any component is an absolute path, all previous path components will be discarded._" `"/files/one.txt"` *is* an absolute path.

Comment: Your first example doesn't produce the output you claim. I think you mean `filepath = '/files/one.txt'`, in which case DYZ's comment applies.

Comment: @DYZ, and how could I convert it to relative by standard methods?

Comment: You can remove the first forward slash, if any.

Comment: Where does the value of `filepath` come from in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On python 3.8.0 it seem to work as expected.

```py
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

filepath = 'files/one.txt'
request_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, filepath)
print(request_path, filepath, BASE_DIR)
```

```sh
$ python -V
Python 3.8.0
$ python /tmp/a.py
/tmp/files/one.txt files/one.txt /tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the f-string in python (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)).

In your case:

```
request_path  = f"{BASE_DIR}/{filepath}"
```

Be aware that you need an extra **slash** "**/**" between your file location variables (BASE_DIR and filepath) to complete the full file location properly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Whys is an f-string better than a specialized library function?

Comment: It's not, though if you are going to hard-code the `/` in `filepath`, you may as well hard-code it every where. `os.path.join` doesn't do much more than save you the trouble of providing a platform-independent path separator.

Comment: os.path.join  is helpful if you need to communicate intelligently with your operating system. As said in the comments: if you have multiple absolute paths, like "/project_folder" and "/User", then os.path.join will find the folder most specific to the file your are aiming for ("/project_folder") and disregard "/User". In your case you might not need this functionality. The less complex approach might be most error-proof.